# How can I make a node js file run on a certain date at a certain time in linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, puppeteer

I will be gone for a weekend and I need a node.js file to run at a specific time and date. I have not found any way to do this through javascript, but apparently cron works (I am running linux).

I created an sh file that runs the nod.js file and had it run through cron, but it did not run at all. I don't know if this has anything to do with Puppeteer + Node.js, but no script ran...

I also tried using the at command but that did not work either

For cron, I added the line:

```
20 14 2 5 * ~/.../start.sh
```

The sh file was:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Documents/node_bot/
node fog1.js
```

Comment: Think about what you told us: "I tried to run a cron job but it didn't work." Now we can assume, that the cron feature in Linux is not generally broken and so I think will be an issue with how you did it - tell us what you did, the code, what have you added where - and then we've a chance to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Please explain what time you're trying to trigger the script and what you think your cron command is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a node application to run a particular piece of code at a particular time you can run a `setTimeout()` recursive "loop" that checks the time every few milliseconds. If the specific time hasn't passed, the `setTimeout()` callback calls itself and the process starts over. However, if the time is passed, execute a specific code block and stop the recursion loop.

```
const triggerTime = new Date(2019, 05, 05, 02, 30, 0, 0)

function otherCodeToRun() {
  // do something...
}

function wait() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const currentTime = new Date()

    if (currentTime >= triggerTime) {
      otherCodeToRun() // not calling wait ends the recursive loop
    } else {
      wait() // recursively call wait after the timeout completes
    }
  }, 1000) // wait 1 second
}
```

Theoretically, that `otherCodeToRun()` function could call another node process to run your other file, or it could load your other file as a module and run it that way.

Also worth noting is that you could perform this check inside a `while` loop, however, the application will block completely, meaning it will appear unresponsive and can take up a lot of CPU cycles. The setTimeout approach gives your application a chance to yield to other processes, allowing you to log output to the console, say, if you want to display a countdown.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably look more like this (absolute paths just in case):

> 20 14 2 5 * cd /path/to/Documents/node_bot && /path/to/node fog1.js

This runs on May 2 at 14:20